# Datepicker / CKEditor won't load unless "Access CRM" is granted

Tags: civievent, acl

Stumbled across this while setting up specific user roles. Created an "Event Manager" who requires access to creating events. ACL is just "Create Events".

1. User can access the Event creation URL just fine "/civicrm/event/add?reset=1&action=add".
2. They can edit the event (fill in fields, etc)
3. They can press "Continue" to save the event.

They CANNOT do the following until they are granted "Access CiviCRM" permissions:

1. Use CKEditor (it does not load)
2. Or the datepicker (it does not load)

It appears additional javascript (or other scripts) are loaded when "Access CiviCRM" is checked.

If this is not a bug, can anyone advise where to look? The reason why we do not want to grant "Access CiviCRM" permissions is because of the Quick Search bar - to which there doesn't seem to be an ability to disable if "Access CiviCRM" is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being more straight-forward - "Access CiviCRM" apparently loads a javascript/jQuery that otherwise isn't loaded if that ACL isn't granted. We updated the templates to load these files regardless of ACL.

In case anyone is curious, we made the following change to file: CRM\Core\Resources.php - we moved the scripts above the Permission Check in case you do want to expose back-office functions (like Creating Events) without granting Access CiviCRM permissions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to grant them "access CiviCRM" and implement a hook to remove the quicksearch bar for those users.